# How can I mathematically represent the change in distance of a particle where the force is a function of its location?

Tags: kinematics, differential-equations

If I have a system of 2 particles, A and B, where the force of particle B on particle A is related to the following equation:

$\frac{3}{b x^4}-\frac{2}{a x^3}=\text{force}$,

where $a$ and $b$ are just constant coefficients - how could I express the movement of particle A (where particle B will be fixed in place for simplicity), if I also know its mass, preferably as a differential equation? Would this system be difficult to solve using analytical methods?

Here is what I have so far:

$\text{$\Delta $x}=a t^2+t v$

$a=\frac{\partial ^2x}{\partial t^2}=\frac{\frac{3}{b x^4}-\frac{2}{a x^3}}{m_A}$

$\text{$\Delta $x}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}*t+\frac{t^2 \left(\frac{3}{b x^4}-\frac{2}{a x^3}\right)}{m_A}$,

but I'm pretty sure I'm messing something up at the last step.

Comment: Use a potential energy function associated with your force. Together with the kinetic energy, invoke the conservation of total energy. Solve for the velocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming constant mass, the differential equation would be

$$m \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \frac{3}{bx^4}-\frac{2}{ax^3}$$

Now you can integrate the differential equation twice and if you know the initial conditions, you can determine the constants and hence determine the equation of motion.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. By chance, do you know of any good books or references to serve as a guide for describing problems with differential equations, like you did here?

Comment: G.F.Simmons "Differential equations: with applications and historical notes" is a very good introductory book in my opinion.

Comment: Great, thank you! It looks really helpful.